# C++ fail opening rocksdb that is written by python

Tags: leveldb, rocksdb, lmdb

I plan to update an online rocksdb through the following steps:

1. copy online.rdb from production enviroment to local machine;
2. use python-rocksdb api to load online.rdb, modify some values and dump to another rdb, say, online_new.rdb;
3. copy online_new.rdb to production enviroment and restart service that consumes rdb.

The issue I met is, when restarting online server (C++), error is thrown when opening new rdb I just wrote:

```
Corruption: VersionEdit: unknown tag
```

I'm confused because I can open online_new.rdb with python successfully but not with C++.
I'm not sure if the discrepancy comes from different options:

- the Options I use when writing rdb in python:

```
opt = rdb.Options()
opt.write_buffer_size = 64 << 20
opt.max_write_buffer_number = 1000
opt.level0_slowdown_writes_trigger = 20
opt.level0_stop_writes_trigger = 24
opt.create_if_missing = True
```

- And Options I use when opening rdb in C++:

```
rocksdb::Options options;
options.IncreaseParallelism();
options.OptimizeLevelStyleCompaction();
options.write_buffer_size = 64 << 20;
options.max_write_buffer_number = 100;
options.level0_slowdown_writes_trigger = 20;
options.db_write_buffer_size = 0;
options.level0_stop_writes_trigger = 24;
options.create_if_missing = true;
options.keep_log_file_num = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely caused by different RocksDB version, looks like your python environment has newer version, which write some tag that your production environment unable to understand. I would suggest to upgrade your production RocksDB version.